# How to declare the Unity InjectionFactory in XML configuration

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container, service-locator

I'm in the process of moving our Unity configuration to the web.config file.  I'm stuck on how to migrate the following code config to the xml format:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IPrincipal>(new InjectionFactory(x=> HttpContext.Current.User));
return container;
```

Here are the XML declartion:

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <alias alias="IRepository" type="Model.IRepository, Model" />        
    <alias alias="Repository" type="Data.Repository, Data" />
    <container>
      <register type="IRepository" mapTo="Repository" />      
    </container>    
</unity>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

InjectionFactory is the one thing that can't be represented in XML out of the box. In order for it to completely work, you'd have to write a C# parser that could work on the XML file, which was way more than I wanted to bite off at the time.

However, I do have [a sample on bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/ctavares/unityfactoryconfig) which shows a way to get a limited version of factory creation working via XML. Might give you some ideas.

Comment: Good to know thanks - A lot more work than i expected, i suppose it's no harm to leave this single exception to be represented as code.